# Is there any way to install helm package in specific node?

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I am trying to install airflow in my kuber cluster(minikube, 3 node) with helm(almost same with original airflow helm chart, except postgresql).
Which node name is airflow-demo(kuber master), airflow-demo-m02, airflow-demo-m03.
However, when I install airflow, each components(pods) are created in seperate node. Which makes scheduler and db does not work(ex: airflow-webserver: airflow-demo-m02, airflow-postgresql-db: airflow-demo-m03 ...)

Am I able to install my helm package in only one node?

What I tried: `helm install ... --set {nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/hostname"="airflow-demo-m02"}`, `helm install ... --set {nodeSelector="airflow-demo-m02"}`, `helm install ... --set nodeSelector.airflowtype=Master` and all did not worked for me.
(nodeSelector.airflowtype is my custom label, airflow-demo-m02 is Master, and airflow-demo-m3 is worker)

Comment: Kubernetes's usual assumption is that all nodes are interconnected, equivalent, and can occasionally get destroyed.  A given Helm chart may or may not support the Kubernetes setup to force something on to a given node, but it also shouldn't be necessary.  What leads you to believe that overriding the placement decision will help?

Comment: @DavidMaze Airflow needs scheduler, db, and webserver pod. In my one docker settings, It runned perfectly. but in kuber, each components became pod, and executed in several nodes. I cannot find a way to interact those three components between nodes(not impossible I believe..some kind of setting in airflow helm?). So I want to install three components in one kuber node. this is the helm chart I reffered to `https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/sample-values-KubernetesExecutor.yaml` thanks in advance

Comment: Overriding the node placement will have no effect on one Pod's ability to reach another through its Service.  That chart does seem to have [settings](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/values.yaml#L173-L189) to affect the placement decision, but I don't think forcing everything on to one node will solve your actual problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze you were right. while playing with airflow, some processes were not terminated in local docker. it was a sample case without scheduler and db, I wasnt avaliable to 'attach' schedulers since it is none. after rebooting node it became fine. Thanks a lot